# Getting Error when I do Grunt grunt serve:dist

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

this is the error log

```
node:10096) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Expected a buffer
(node:10096) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): TypeError: Expected a buffer
(node:10096) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 4): TypeError: Expected a buffer Use --force to continue.
```

Comment: I could give you a better answer if you provide more data to the question, for example, showing your gruntfile

Comment: sorry for that my gruntfile is so big too show

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommended not to do --force in grunt serve command. But you have a warning, so, maybe for you in this case, if you run `grunt serve --force` you can find where in the code (or the gruntfile) you have the TypeError.

Do you have install mozjpeg? Try downgrading mozjpeg to version 5.1.0

Comment: Running "imagemin:dist" (imagemin) task
Fatal error: stream.on is not a function this is the error

Comment: Can u plz help me

Comment: I have tried with grunt serve:dist --force but it is working fine but still getting error on  
Running "imagemin:dist" (imagemin)     Error is: task Fatal error: stream.on is not a function

Comment: Here's my imagemin task in my GruntFile.js:    imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },

Comment: i am getting that error after run: grunt imagemin Running "imagemin:dist" (imagemin) task Fatal error: stream.on is not a function

Comment: Do you have install mozjpeg? Try downgrading mozjpeg to version 5.1.0